# is there another alternative than trying to make iloc or loc or lambda work to iterate over rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

dataset = [(2, 4, 6, 43, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan),

           (10, 12, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan),

           (20, 22, 24, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan),

           (10, 12, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan),

           (10, 12, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan),

           (20, 22, 24, 60, np.nan, np.nan, 60, 4),

           (10, 12, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 60, 4),

           (10, 12, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 60, 4),

           (20, 22, 24, 13, np.nan, np.nan, 13, 60),

           (10, 12, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 13, 60),

           (20, 22, 24, 26, np.nan, np.nan, 26, 13),

           (28, 30, 32, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 26, 13)]

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "1 prev D", "2 prev D", "1 prev D example", "2 prev D example" ))

## 1 prev d example = if D == np.nan look 1 cell above
## 2 prev d example = if 1 prev D example == D, look 1 cell above D, if np.nan, look 1 cell above again
```

i have done circles with loc and iloc and lambda, and trying to work out the obvious "go to method" for iterating time stamped data

Comment: Iteration is usually a last resort when dealing with pandas/numpy. What are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to record the last 2 values of D ignoring nan values

Comment: Huh? Are you trying to **fill** `NaN` values? Or are you trying to simply access non-`NaN` values?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment was not super clear, but if all you want are the last two non-`NaN` values from column `D` then use masking to ignore `NaN` and then slice:

```py
In [4]: df[df["D"].notnull()][-2:]
Out[4]:
     A   B   C     D  1 prev D  2 prev D  1 prev D example  2 prev D example
8   20  22  24  13.0       NaN       NaN              13.0              60.0
10  20  22  24  26.0       NaN       NaN              26.0              13.0
```

Again, not really sure what the other columns are for or if this is actually what you want.

Please update your original post with an example of your expected output if this answer isn't sufficient.

Comment: trying to make "1 prev D", "2 prev D" equal the same as "1 prev D example", "2 prev D example". i manually created the example columns to show how the other 2 will look afterwards

Comment: Why is `43.0` not in any of your example columns? According to your logic, row 1 column "D" should get 43.0 because its original value is `NaN` and therefore it should look one cell above.

Comment: well picked up, correct it should be

Comment: Gotcha. Can you update your post to reflect your expected output? For `"1 prev D"` you can get this simply with `df["D"].ffill()`. I'm still not sure what you're looking for with `2 prev D` and would appreciate a clear example.